# Naive implementation of a callback: How do I stop the stack growing?

Tags: python, callback, stack, stack-overflow

I've just learnt about the concept of callbacks, I decided to try implementing my own. My efforts were fruitful, I did indeed manage to simulate the functionality of a callback. Unfortunately, I noticed that my implementation resulted in the stack growing by 2 function calls every cycle which, I assume, would eventually result in a stack overflow  if the code ran for a sufficient amount of time.

I was wondering, how could I implement this code to prevent the stack growing on each cycle? Or is this an inevitable product of this implementation, in which case how would this issue be circumvented?

```py
import time
import inspect 

def doSomething(x):
    return x + 0.00000001

def continue_processing(runningTotal,termination_condition,callback,callback_args,timeout=5):
    startTime = time.time()
    while (time.time() - startTime < timeout and not(termination_condition(runningTotal))):
        runningTotal = doSomething(runningTotal)

    print(f"Returning control to calling function, running total is {runningTotal}")
    return callback(runningTotal,*callback_args)

def process(runningTotal,n,beginTime):

    if(runningTotal < n):
        print(f"Continue processing, running total is {runningTotal}\nTime elapsed {time.time() - beginTime}\nCurrent stack size: {len(inspect.stack())}")
        continue_processing(runningTotal,lambda x: x>n,process,(n,beginTime))

if __name__ == '__main__':

    beginTime = time.time()
    try:
        process(0,1,beginTime)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program interrupted!")
        exit(0)
    print(f"Completed in {time.time() - beginTime}"
```

Comment: Your callback calls "process" which in turn calls the callback which... and so on. A callback should usually not do this.

Comment: Also your code is not asynchronous at all. (you might think so if you added this tag to the question).

Comment: I understand that the example here is synchronous, I included async because callbacks are related to async programming, or am I incorrect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the callback is recursive, it calls itself (indirectly) — which is why the stack overflows. Below is how to avoid that. Note I also changed your code to conform to the [PEP 8 - Style Guide for Python Code](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) guidelines to make it more readable. I strongly suggest you read and follow it, especially if you're just learning the language.

```
import time
import inspect


def doSomething(x):
    return x + 0.00000001

def continue_processing(runningTotal, termination_condition, timeout=5):
    startTime = time.time()
    while (time.time() - startTime < timeout
            and not(termination_condition(runningTotal))):
        runningTotal = doSomething(runningTotal)

    print(f"Returning control to calling function, running total is "
          f"{runningTotal}")

    # Don't call back the callback
    #return callback(runningTotal, *callback_args)

def process(runningTotal, n, beginTime):
    while runningTotal < n:
        print(f"Continue processing, running total is {runningTotal}\n"
              f"Time elapsed {time.time() - beginTime}\n"
              f"Current stack size: {len(inspect.stack())}")
        continue_processing(runningTotal, lambda x: x>n)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    beginTime = time.time()
    try:
        process(0, 1, beginTime)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Program interrupted!")
        exit(0)
    print(f"Completed in {time.time() - beginTime}")
```

Comment: Thanks Martineau, how would you implement a proper callback function, I believe the example you've corrected to would work only for a synchronous process?

Comment: Thanks Martineau, it seems my question is therefore too vague. I shall explore more and perhaps post another, more specific, example.